# CSS scrollbar with max-height depending on screen resolution height

Tags: css, scrollbar, screen, resolution

I have a problem using as browser Internet Explorer 11 both in native and compatibility mode.

As this webapp i'm developing should work on different screen resolution i would like to have scrollbar with max-height adaptable to the actual screen resolution.

I've tried to make it this way, but it doesn't work.

Wrote a function getheight that gives me the resolution height:

```
public double getheight() {
    return java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice().getDisplayMode().getHeight();
}
```

Tried also this similar funcion but still doesn't work

```
public double getheight() {
    Dimension screensize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    return screensize.getHeight();
}
```

Then in the css sheets i'm using

```
<ul style="max-height: <%=getheight()*0.54%>px; overflow-y: auto; overflow-x: hidden">
```

All this works when I test the app locally, when i deploy the app on a server and the connect to the server to use it, the scrollbar stops adapting.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: are you missing a % on your closing `<%=getheight()*0.54>`?

Comment: @Pete Sorry, i copied wrong the code. It's not working for other reasons.